# C# SSH.NET - one SSH connection vs multiple SSH connections

Tags: c#, mysql, database, ssh, ssh.net

I have a C# application which uses the [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) library to connect to a server. The application executes SQL commands to the database through multiple methods.

Is it better to have one long-running SSH connection that encompasses all SQL commands, eg:

```
using (var sshClient = getSshClient()))
{
    sshClient.Connect();

    if (sshClient.IsConnected)
    {
        using (var portForward = setupPortForward()))
        {
            sshClient.AddForwardedPort(setupPortForward());
            portForward.Start();

            // Start SQL commands

            if (!sshClient.IsConnected) {
                sshClient.Connect();
            }
            else {
                executeSQLCommand1();
            }

            if (!sshClient.IsConnected) {
                sshClient.Connect();
            }
            else {
                executeSQLCommand2();
            }

            // End SQL commands

            portForward.Stop();
            sshClient.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Or to open an SSH connection at the start of each SQL statement?

```
using (var sshClient = setupSshClient()))
{
    sshClient.Connect();

    if (sshClient.IsConnected)
    {
        using (var portForward = setupPortForward()))
        {
            sshClient.AddForwardedPort(portForward);
            portForward.Start();

            executeSQLCommand1();

            portForward.Stop();
            sshClient.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}

using (var sshClient = setupSshClient()))
{
    sshClient.Connect();

    if (sshClient.IsConnected)
    {
        using (var portForward = setupPortForward()))
        {
            sshClient.AddForwardedPort(portForward);
            portForward.Start();

            executeSQLCommand2();

            portForward.Stop();
            sshClient.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

The server is known to sometimes drop connections, so I imagine the second method is better in terms 'cleaner' logic for re-establishing a connection? Or are there any other better ways for reconnecting?

Comment: If the server tends to drop connections, it can drop one even in a middle of some command. So you will have to deal with reconnect in any case.

Comment: How long does it take to setup+setup+forward+start+stop+disconnect?  Your second option is limiting MySQL's queries-per-second to that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing an SSH connection followed by sql commands as opposed to using the relavent database client library?  This whole approach (whether long running or single command) is likely to cause you issues when the connection has dropped and error handling which would be considerably easier to handle if you were using a database client.  Some issues that will be difficult to handle are if the connection drops, did the last SQL command complete successfully?  Even if the connection stays alive parsing the output stream for errors is going to be troublesome.

Comment: What are your transactional requirements?  Is each of the sql commands atomic or do they need to be wrapped in a transaction, if so then you need the first long running connection approach.

Answer (score 5):

### Part 1: Minimize the connection lifetime.

A common "best practice" with **SQL connections** is that you want to **minimize the connection open time** - this means that you open the connection just before you execute your query and close it just after that. Same applies to **SSH connections**.

The dangling resources that you do not dispose of after their use have a name and they are referred to as **memory leaks**.

### Part 2: Use the transactions to ensure DB state consistency

If a single statement in your SQL query transactions fails then the transaction will fail. You want to fail, roll back the state DB was in before the error ex: connection dropped and retry later.

If you do not need logging of the error then you can use `set xact_abort on` before your transaction to rolls back automatically in case of error ex: timeout or drop the connection.

For more info

- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29312
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40078.sql-server-set-xact-abort-vs-try-catch.aspx

### Part 3: Create a retry policy

Generally, the best practice is that you do not want to avoid failure but instead accept it, fail fast and have a way to try again. What kind of policy you pick for the retry is up to you.

If you want to do anything more complex than manual retry then I would recommend that you take a look at Rx observable (reactive extension) or Polly. It does have a bit of a learning curve, but you get used to it.

```
 // Policy to retry 5 times, waiting {2, 4, 8, 16, 32} seconds between retries.
 var policy = Policy
   .Handle<SqlException>()
   .WaitAndRetry(5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

 policy.Execute(() => UpdateDatabase1(obj1));
```